# Why all LEDs of my HP Proliant DL380 G8 server flashing amber?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, vmware-vsphere, hp-proliant

I'm using a **HP Proliant DL380 G8** Server for 2 years with a **VMWare ESXi 6u2** OS installed on it. Recently I have noticed that all systems insight display LEDs are flashing amber (screenshot in [this](http://pasteboard.co/18tGpnzy9.jpg) link). but the Health LED is solid green. also in my

> VMWare vsphere client --> Health Status

all entities are green. you can see screenshot in [this](http://pasteboard.co/bmQDNoYJY.png) link. Does anyone know why this would happen? Is this  dangerous or critical state?

Comment: Surely the user manual will answer this question.

Comment: And if not, check iLO, not the configuration overview of a 3rd party application.

Answer (score 4):

The ILO interface or system IML log will tell you what's wrong.

In addition, the errors or any critical system issues will be reported at [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).

If you're using an HP version of ESXi, the system health should be reported in vCenter.

There are a number of ways to see what's wrong here, but you should do some basic troubleshooting first. The System Insight Display could also be bad.